# Set multiple SelectList values on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a form that contains a multiple selectlist and I also use bootstrap selectpicker with this.

***code***:

***model***:

```
    [Display(Name = "SystemTyp")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vänligen välj typ")]
    public List<SelectListItem> SystemTypes { get; set; }
```

***view***:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("SystemTyp", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("SystemTypes",
           RegistrationHandlers.GetSystemtypes()
           ,
           new { @class = "form-control", @multiple = "multiple", @title = "---  Välj Systemtyp  ---" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SystemTypes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

When posting:

[image]

Every time I post the list is empty. 
The list name matches the model property name.

What am I missing?

I have another list that is a single select so the selected value is a simple string and this works fine but the above is giving me a headache.

Comment: You `SelectList` property is named `SystemTypes` and the view code you have shown does not use that anywhere. All you have shown is a `DropDownList()` method that binds to a property named `UserRole`

Comment: Copied the wrong dropdownlist, sorry, check edits

Comment: `SystemTypes` is your `SelectList`. You cannot bind to a `SelectList`. Your property needs to be (say) `IEnumerable<int> SystemTypes` (a `<select>` element only posts back an array of simple values)

Comment: And do not use `DropDownList()` - use `ListBoxFor(m => m.SystemTypes, RegistrationHandlers.GetSystemtypes(), new { ... })` which is the correct way to generate a `<select multiple>`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke as of late you are like a guardian angel. thanks m8

Comment: @StephenMuecke **is** an angel... (no-homo...)

Comment: hahahhahaha I like the (no-homo) edit. Developer skill level = precise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inderstand that `DropDownList` helper creates `select` tag with `name="SystemTypes"` attribute in html markup.

On **POST** in passes selected value with `UserRole` name.

And you don't need whoule list on POST you need only selected value so create `SystemTypeId` property in your `ViewModel` and change your helper to this:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("SystemTypeId", <-- note this
           RegistrationHandlers.GetSystemtypes()
           ,
           new { @class = "form-control", @multiple = "multiple", @title = "---  Välj Systemtyp  ---" })
```

Then you will get selected value in your binded model.

Don't try to get whoulde list back - you don't need it.

If you need to select ***multiple*** you should use `ListBox` helper:

```
@Html.ListBox("SystemTypeIds", <-- note this
               RegistrationHandlers.GetSystemtypes()
               ,
               new { @class = "form-control", @title = "---  Välj Systemtyp  ---" })
```

`SystemTypeIds` property should be `Array` or `IEnumerable<int>` or `IList<int>` to bind correctry. (ofcource it could be not  only `int` but `string`, `bool` etc..)

If you searching for best way to achive that i suggest you to use Strongly typed helper - `ListBoxFor`:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SystemTypeIds
               ,RegistrationHandlers.GetSystemtypes()
               ,new { @class = "form-control", @title = "---  Välj Systemtyp  ---" })
```

Comment: Sorry, in my hase and frustration i copied the wrong code. Check edits.
I want only the selected values

Comment: The thing you are describing is if i select only one item in the list. But when i select multiple?

Comment: I would suggest using the `ListBoxFor()` method, and passing the Model Property to it - saves headaches when refactoring :)

Comment: @teovankot Then suggest that, too. Yes we're here to help try and solve the OP's problem - but if we can suggest better practices to solve deeper issues, then bonus points all round!

Comment: Worked when i changed to IEnumerable<int> and I tried using the listbox aswell and it works. Thanks!

Comment: @GeoffJames added, ok

Comment: `ListBox()` and `ListBoxFor()` add the `multlple` attribute :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ooops. my bad, didn't see that

Comment: @StephenMuecke fix